# The result of bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo command

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cli, peers, port

When I type `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` in shell, conspicuous property of the result are `addr` and `addrlocal` `addrbind`.

[image]

14.xx is my address and others are peer's address.
**I know that Bitcoin client can do port forwarding using UPnP query to my router.
so, I checked my router whether the port number(48302, 44660) is opened or not but, no any port is currently open.** 
This is very strange point. my peers should cannot communicate with me without port forwarding since I'm using router.

Can you give information technically?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so, I checked my router whether the port number(48302, 44660) is opened or not but, no any port is currently open.

They don't appear open because those ports are not always open listening for incoming connections. Rather those ports are bound to temporarily by the forwarding software which then initiates the connection to your computer. As soon as the connection to the peer closes, so will that port.

What you see with that is like the ports that your browser uses to connect to remote web servers. When you have your browser open, a port is opened. But if you port scan your own computer, you won't see those ports. You can see what ports are active and connected to other servers by using the `netstat -nap` command.

Comment: Thank for replying :)  I'd like to search detail about your first paragraph. can you give some keyword?

Comment: @Hyunsoo Perhaps read up on how TCP works? Both outgoing and incoming connections use TCP ports, but for outgoing connections they're randomly selected non-open ports.